# 502 error from nginx. It doesn't seem to be listening to any port, but will connect to default

Tags: nginx, port, gunicorn, flask

Facts: Nginx default can be accessed. Gunicorn is running, the website can be accessed via LAN. Nginx runs, does not give me any errors. When I check `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` , it tells me Nginx is not listening to anything, and that port 80 and 443 are open.

I was following [this tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) to build a Flask website, and everything has been functioning great until the end. I have Gunicorn serving it at `localhost:8000`, and can access it via other computers at its LAN address. Yet when I try to access it online from `74.114.75.91`, my static ip, I just get a 502.
Here my `sites-available` code.

```
server {
    # listen on port 80 (http)
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    location / {
         # redirect any requests to the same URL but on https
         return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }

server {
    # listen on port 443 (https)
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name _;

    # location of the self-signed SSL certificate
    ssl_certificate /home/pi/farmData/certs/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/pi/farmData/certs/key.pem;

    # write access and error logs to /var/log
    access_log /var/log/farmData_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/farmData_error.log;

    location / {
        # forward application requests to the gunicorn server
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /static {
        # handle static files directly, without forwarding to the application
        alias /home/pi/farmData/app/static;
        expires 30d;
    }
}
```

Comment: sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN gives me the same result as  netstat -an | grep LISTEN  , so I guess my conclusion is pretty good.

Comment: Usually (on Linux) I'd use `netstat -nltp`, though. Anyway, how did you get that static IP? I ask that because depending on your network setup, packets from Internet may be not forwarded to your machine. In home network case it often involves port forwarding in the modem/router.

Comment: It's a static Ip i purchased from my network provider

Comment: Check the nginx error log.

Answer (score 0):

Your statements are contradictory.

You are stating: "gunicorn is running at localhost:8000" and "can access it via other computers at its LAN address".

If Gunicorn is listening to `localhost:8000`, it cannot communicate with LAN clients. If Gunicorn is listening at `<lan_ip>:8000`, nginx cannot communicate with it using `localhost:8000` address.

You need to make sure Gunicorn is listening to `localhost:8000` address.